# Reorder table data with issues to analysis

Tags: sql-server, application-design

I am using SQL Server 2008.

[image]

1. The table of products above was created from data from another table.
   PRODUCT_SORT is the result of sorting the PRODUCT and EVENT_ORDER together
2. Non Product records were inserted (lines in Yellow) from other sources
3. Table sorted by SERIALNO and DATE

[image]

**Problem:**

- In the table above, the products PROD_03 and PROD_04 are OK (green) and PROD_01 and PROD_02 are NOT OK (red)
- The two records of each product must be together and sorted as in the first table at the top

**The goal is:**
Due to registration, I found many mistakes, so I have to do some corrections to put it in order to make the analysis

**Brainstorming my ideas:**

- I've thinking on how to do some king of sorting
- Maybe to have a Product table and non product table. Create a loop and insert records from one and the other

**I am here just to ask for some approaches** on how to resolve these problems. That's it, **no code needed!**

**Result table**

- The two records of each product must be together and sorted as in the first table at the top.
- Non product records must be between two different products ordered by date.

[image]

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: You don't expect the data to be sorted **inside** the Table itself, right?...as Tables have no guaranteed order to them. But you can achieve a definitive ordering with the `ORDER BY` clause, which can be stored in a View or some other object, if you want it to be repeatable.

Comment: How can I use an ´Order By´  and achieve what I am looking for?  If it was that simple I would not need to create this post.

Comment: I wasn't saying the solution can be achieved with a simple `ORDER BY` clause alone, rather I just wanted to make sure you weren't expecting a Table to maintain order on its own. But yes an `ORDER BY` clause with a hard-coded `CASE` statement could solve your specific example. Though I assume you have more data than what's shown, so it probably wouldn't be a complete solution. Maybe you could elaborate on how your result table is ordered currently (as at first glance it appears random).

Comment: Just to add a bit: an ORDER BY in a VIEW doesn't cut it. It isn't allowed, unless you use TOP (or similar). But if you use the old TOP 100% PERCENT "workaround", then the optimizer will in the plan remove the TOP and ORDER BY. I.e., the ordering need to be performed when consuming the data ("when the data leaves SQL Server and travels to the client application").

Comment: @J.D, I just put the only two rules to order the data. The table is quite big. The table refers to serial numbers and the products and events related to them. The main goal is to have the table ordered but  taking in account the 2 rules.

Comment: "The main goal is to have the table ordered..." A table isn't ordered. You can only order the result from a query, not the table itself. (Just to be clear and avoid further possible confusions.)